# Is it ok to run 14 gauge wire for lighting off of a chain of 12 gauge outlets on a 20 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

So, I had a friend wire my basement for me because even though I had a basic understanding of it, I wasn't 100% comfortable with doing it alone (he's been working construction for several years now). I noticed he wired a string of 8 outlets and then two can lights in the bar. He used 12 gauge wire for all the outlets but 14 gauge for the lights. All this is running on a 20 amp breaker. From what I've read, this is technically not code, but I'm not too concerned with that. I just want to know if it's safe. I also wanted to add an outlet to the circuit for under the bar for a mini fridge, so I'm thinking I need the 20 amp breaker for that reason, otherwise I'd just switch it to a 15 amp breaker. Any thoughts?

Comment: "this is technically not code, but I'm not too concerned with that. I just want to know if it's safe." - the code isn't just some arcane ritual performer to satisfy some bureaucrat, it's literally a collection of rules that defines a safe system, written out of the blood and ash of people injured or killed in electrical accidents. Take it seriously.

Comment: Really. Every rule in Code is because a sufficiently large number of accident reports came in to justify the rule. Putting 15A light branches on 20A circuits is one of those things.

Comment: And by the way, this *is precisely why nobody can work on other's houses without a pro license*.  Your friend has no risk here.  You have skin in the game, since you pay the ultimate price for blunders.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I pretty much agree with you, but, and here's the but: In the 2020 code nearly everything in a home has to have GFCI protection....water heaters, furnaces, outdoor HVAC units, Ranges.  I believe some of the rules like this are driven by electrical manufacturers who would much rather sell you a $45 breaker than a $4 breaker. I believe GFCI/AFCI protection is warranted for convenience outlets and lighting, but for properly grounded, permanently installed equipment is over-kill. Not only that nuisance trips on freezers and fridges has destroyed a lot of food.

Comment: @George Industry manipulation is a factor, but there's meat to it.  A great many lives *would be* saved if AFCI were commonplace, so the data supports it.  However behind the aggregates is the fact that the casualties *are in old housing stock*.  If the city put down an entitlement rule that "to build this 1000-house development you must kit out 1000 older homes with AFCI"... *that* would have the intended impact. It would also be "socialism", and we can't have that!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  That's a great point. Houses without grounded outlets do have much higher risk than ones with grounds. I remember using an old power , metal cased drill I'd borrow and using it outside, zapped the heck out of me bc it was internally shorted to the case. Double insulated drills minimized that risk for ungrounded connections, grounding is better and GFCI is best.  I just don't think it's needed for properly grounded, permanently installed equipment.   Maybe a compromise position that when a house is sold, it needs to be upgraded.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  regarding licensing...is that true everywhere?   I thought I could help wiring a friend/relatives house without a license, just so I didn't get paid for it in any way other than appreciation.   Also, I don't believe you need to be licensed to "pull rope" meaning just drilling holes and pulling cables, but not making actual connections.   Please let me know, thanks so much.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson you need to be under the supervision of someone who does have the right to do the work... e.g. the homeowner in an owner-occupied.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Gotcha. Thanks. Good, that would be the case in all the electrical work I've done for friends and family, so I'm golden! Although the term "supervision" would need to be taken lightly!  Mostly the reason I "helped" was that the homeowner didn't have the skills to do it right and I didn't want them to try, screw it up, have multiple findings on inspection, some which can be very difficult to fix. All of my electrical work either passed first time or with very minor findings, like you need arc fault on these circuits or the neutral main wasn't code taped white, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I should've just done it myself and it would've been correct. 15 amp should be fine for the whole circuit. Most of the outlets will not be used, maybe a vacuum or a phone charger from time to time, otherwise just a mini fridge, blender and TV for the bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is it "technically not code", it is **not to code** and could be  dangerous. If you need a 20 amp breaker, then you have to change that wire to 12 AWG.  It might be easier to run a new 20 Amp circuit to the bar and change the lighting circuit to a 15 Amp breaker although 8 outlets is a lot for a 15 Amp breaker. This is the kind of stuff that can kill a sale in the future or be a reason to insurance companies to drop you.

Comment: Maybe you need the 20A breaker for a dehumidifier or some other basement gadget?  You don't need one for a mini fridge so a variation of this answer would be to install a new circuit for the device that needs 20A and use a 15A breaker for the existing circuit.

Comment: Just curious - is there a concept of protecting this extended line with 15 amp breaker right  from where it starts (some junction box)? If yes - would it be sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

Giving your friend the benefit of the doubt, he may be misapplying exception 1 of 210.19(A)(4) exception 1a:

> ```
> Exception No.1: Tap conductors shall have an ampacity
> sufficient for the load served. In addition, they shall have an
> ampacity of not less than 15 for circuits rated less than
> 40 amperes and not less than 20 for circuits rated at 40 or
> 50 amperes and only where these tap conductors supply
> any of the following loads:
>
>   (a) Individual lampholders or luminaires (fixtures)
>   with taps extending not longer than 450 mm (18 in.) beyond
>   any portion of the lampholder or luminaire (fixture).
> ```

Basically this means you can use 14 AWG for pigtails for connecting light fixtures, when the light fixture is only rated for 15 amp or less, but those pigtails must be shorter than 18 inches. What your friend did, which was to use 14 AWG from an outlet or switch to the fixture, which almost surely exceeds 18 inches, is not allowed. If that 18 inches is exceeded the full requirements of 210.19(A)(1) must be met:

> 1. General. Branch-circuit conductors shall have an ampacity not less than the maximum load to be served.

You should switch to a 15 amp breaker. And tell your friend he needs to review his material before he starts helping on other people's homes.

Comment: The friend isn't licensed to work on other people's homes.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, a mini-fridge could use a 6 amp breaker, if we even had that kind of thing in this country.  Fridges are very small loads - stick a 'Kill-a-Watt' meter on one sometime.

Our own main fridge consumes 120 VA (1.0 amps) *while it is running*, and *averages* 36 watts (0.3A) on a continuous basis.  I need just shy of 1.0 KWH per day to keep it going in an outage (which is important to battery sizing).  We're talking a golf cart battery per day, more or less.

If you have anything important in that mini-fridge that would be hazardous if it spent time at room temperature, then I would have a dedicated circuit just for the fridge.  You don't want a situation where the circuit trips, and later someone resets it because they need *a different outlet* to be hot, and never realizes the fridge was also on it and everything is full of bacteria now.

That also allows you to put bare minimum circuit protection (AFCI/GFCI) on it, to reduce the chance of a nuisance trip from those. Fridges don't really need GFCI protection, and on a dedicated fridge circuit, AFCI is fairly pointless if the cable is metal-armored.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, you are also not allowed to install lighting on 20 amp breakers in a dwelling (at least not in Canada, CEC 30-104). Will this start a fire or cause some other danger making this unsafe? I would say no, not in itself...we are talking about an additional 5 amps and to be honest, that 14awg wire could easily handle that, which those lights will never draw anyways. The more likely thing to happen is a short circuit, which the 20 amp breaker will trip just as quickly from. But the reason for the code rule is likely more to do with keeping things conformed to a standard. If you allow this in this particular situation, then it complicates things and can lead to more dangerous wiring habits. Placing restrictions like this helps keep the trade safe, even if it comes at the cost of convenience and is actually unnecessary in a particular instance. The better thing to do is take the lighting off the 20 amp circuit and feed it from another lighting circuit. May require more wiring and work, but it is a better installation and will meet all the code rules. If you overload the circuit causing the breaker to trip, all your lights will still be on so you can see.

Comment: Fascinating. So where (as I understand it) in the US you could, if you wanted to, wire up all regular receptacles *and* lighting on 20A circuits with 12 AWG wiring, in Canada you must (as in the US) have *some* receptacle circuits on 20A but lighting must be 15A. What about bathrooms? AIUI, in the US a bathroom requires a 20A receptacle circuit and that can be shared with multiple bathrooms *or* with lighting in the same bathroom. In Canada it sounds like you couldn't do that - so lighting would *have* to be on a separate circuit.