can 14ga wire be used off of a 20amp GFI
I am installing a lighted bathroom mirror, which has 14ga wire. Can I connect this to a 20amp GFI receptacle?

Possible duplicate: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/218202/is-it-ok-to-run-14-gauge-wire-for-lighting-off-of-a-chain-of-12-gauge-outlets-on

Check the wiring and circuit breaker for that GFCI receptacle. If it is 14-gauge and 15 amps, then the 20-amp GFCI is oversized and should be replaced with a 15-amp GFCI. (Replacing a dead 15-amp outlet with a 20-amp accidentally is a really easy mistake; folks may not really grasp why some outlets have the T slot and some don't, and just grab the first one to hand.)

Is the breaker that the GFCI is on 15A or 20A?  If the latter, you may not use a 14g cable.

@Huesmann this is the fixture wire.  The fixture is rated to use it so the fixture will never pull enough to cause a problem.  Fixture wires are often higher gauge than the circuit wire.  Most light fixtures have smaller diameter wires that connect up to 14g light circuits.

Dump question:  Are you just plugging the lighted mirror into the receptacle?  As in...plugging it in like any other appliance?  Or are you talking about hard-wiring to the inside of the receptacle?

If it comes with the fixture and the fixture has UL or similar listed testing labels, yes.
This does not allow you to add 14ga wire to a 20 amp circuit yourself.
That fixture should have been tested to say the short 14ga wire for connection is okay.
UL, ETL, CSA are recognized testing labels.  CE is not recognize in North America and any fixtures with only the CE mark should not be connected.
